Trying to fix my recursive patch-finder, it needs to recursevely find the divisions of a patch storing info about the color of the divider line
Testing i found out that the error lays on the construction of the color_hierarchy list, i actually figured out that it doesn't add every division color to the list every time it has to... sorry for my poor writing, and thanks you all!
I also tried to use the min function, but it always made things worse i couldn't figure out why
So this is my code,
def recursive_patch_count(image, x_start, y_start, x_end, y_end, background_color):
    # Dicts for tracing color info
    visited_row_counts = {}
    visited_col_counts = {}
    first_color_coords_row = {}
    first_color_coords_col = {}

    # Building the dicts
    for x in range(x_start, x_end):
        color = image[x][0]
        if visited_row_counts.get(color, 0) == 0:
            first_color_coords_row[color] = x
        visited_row_counts[color] = visited_row_counts.get(color, 0) + 1
    
    for y in range(y_start, y_end):
        color = image[0][y]
        if visited_col_counts.get(color, 0) == 0:
            first_color_coords_col[color] = y
        visited_col_counts[color] = visited_col_counts.get(color, 0) + 1

    # BaseCase (when a patch is empty)
    if len(visited_row_counts) == 1 or len(visited_col_counts) == 1:
        return 1, []
    else:
        div_color_col = None
        div_color_row = None
        # least frequent color in the column/row
        min = visited_row_counts.get(background_color)
        for color in visited_row_counts:
            if visited_row_counts[color] < min:
                div_color_row = color
        for color in visited_col_counts:
            if visited_col_counts[color] < min:
                div_color_col = color

        # Finding division coords
        div_y = first_color_coords_col.get(div_color_col)
        div_x = first_color_coords_row.get(div_color_row)

        # recursive calls
        patch_count, color_hierarchy = 1, []
        for start_x, end_x, start_y, end_y in [(x_start, div_x-1, y_start, div_y-1), (div_x+1, x_end, y_start, div_y-1), (x_start, div_x, div_y+1, y_end), (div_x+1, x_end, div_y+1, y_end)]:
            new_patch_count , new_color_hierarchy = recursive_patch_count(image, start_x, start_y, end_x, end_y, background_color)
            patch_count += new_patch_count
            color_hierarchy.extend(new_color_hierarchy)
            
        color_hierarchy.append(div_color_row)

        return patch_count, color_hierarchy

I was also trying to make this function computationally speaking the best i could, but every time i tried to think about a smart way to code something it didn't work well, this is the best i could do.
